# What's the OST from HxH in episode 148 at 0:31?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

What's the OST from *Hunter x Hunter* episode 148 at 0:31?

Answer (score 0):

It is *Chasing After a Dream* which can be listened to [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mguKt8efSV4).

In searching for this OST, I found this amazing list of every OST from every episode with timestamps. Pretty amazing list. [Here it is](https://sites.google.com/site/hxh2011ostlist/arcs/7-chairman-election-arc).

Happy Hunting!